# Storing key value pair in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my html input elements

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
     <input type="text" name="Key" class="form-control" placeholder="Key">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" name="Value" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
     <input type="text" name="Key" class="form-control" placeholder="Key">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" name="Value" class="form-control" placeholder="Value"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get all 'Key' and 'Value' pair and save them to array using Jquery? Like this `result =[ {'Key' : 'Value'}, {'Key' : 'Value'} ];`

Comment: I have 2 text input inside each form-group. Now I enter key and value to the input text and save them to an array folow key value pair and alert() them

Answer (score 0):

I myself am learning javascript and jQuery, but since you haven't shown any concrete attempt and getting a solution, I can describe how to go about getting what I think you want done. I am working based on what I've already seen in jQuery, not much compared to a lot of eyes that visit this site, and did some googling myself to confirm some things. That said, here is a description of how I think I can arrive at your desired result.

Here is an example as text to help you get through your example. Since you have each pair of inputs in a div with a consistent class name, you can lookup all elements for that class with `$(".form-group")`. Once you have your array of pairs, you can take things to the next level. Next you can use jQuery's `each()` function to iterate over the contents of the array. For each element of the array you can use the find() function to find the inputs with a name "Key" and "Value". At that point you can populate your JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

I've made you a [basic fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdoejtbk/);

so basically using jQuery's `each()` function you can loop through your form-groups and get the key and values and push them into your array.

```js
//defining your empty array here
var arr = [];
//setting up the click function to return your array in console.
$('.cnsllog').on('click', function() {
  //go through all the form groups
  $('.form-group').each(function() {
    //set the input with name equal to value as value variable
    value = $(this).find("input[name='Value']").val()
      //set the input with name equal to Keyas value Key
    key = $(this).find("input[name='Key']").val()
      //push these two variables to your array
    arr.push({
      key: key,
      value: value
    })
  });
  console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" name="Key" class="form-control" placeholder="Key">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" name="Value" class="form-control" placeholder="Value" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" name="Key" class="form-control" placeholder="Key">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" name="Value" class="form-control" placeholder="Value" />
  </div>
</div>
<button class="cnsllog">put the array in console</button>
```